# Scale SVG to fill parent div/td

Tags: html, css, svg

I want the SVG to completely fit the containing TD.  The SVG's proportions don't have to be preserved.  Instead, the SVG's height is the same as its width when the height should be larger than it's width.  There is padding below and above the SVG.  Here's what I have:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

.td-svg {
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
}

.div-svg {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='td-svg'>
        <div class='div-svg'>
          <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio="none"></svg></div></td>
      <td>col 2</td>
      <td>col 3<br/>continued<br/>continued<br/>continued<br/>continued</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I thought the reason the SVG was not filling the entire cell was because the DIV was not filling the parent TD, but if I remove the DIV, I get the same results.

What seems to be happening is that the browser is scaling the SVG to be in proportion to the viewBox dimensions.  Right now in the code above, the SVG element is 70x70.  If change the viewBox to `viewBox='0 0 100 50'`, the SVG element is 70x35.  The TD is 70x92, so I want the SVG to also be 70x92.

By the way, the SVG is positioned differently in the code snippet output versus if you copy the code into a file and run it.

Answer (score 1):

By default,  element is displayed as an inline element aligned to the text baseline. This results in a small amount of space between the bottom of the  element and the bottom of its parent. This space is reserved for text characters that descend below the baseline.

In your example, you can solve your problem by setting display="block" on the  element. For example...

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 100 100' display="block" preserveAspectRatio="none"></svg>
```

Comment: I've tried that and ```style='display: block;' ```.  Neither help.

Comment: What browser and device are you using? I tested in IE11 and Chrome on Windows laptop machine. I tested with and without setting display attribute. I used browser's developer tools to check the layout size for the svg, div, and td elements. Without setting the display attribute, the svg element's height was about 4 pixels smaller that the div's and dt's height. With setting display attribute to "block", the svg element's height was equal to the div's and dt's height.

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Windows.  I see that both the SVG and DIV is 70x70, but the TD is 70x92.  The DIV is centered in the TD.